# How to work with field of inherited classes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Suppose, i have main class for data representation and this class have configuration field. This field must be able to answer some questions related to main class (assume, that this is one question - 'IsMainClassReadyToUse'). But inner structure of this class may be different.

Because of it, i want create `abstract class Configurator` and depending on situation use various `Configuratos` that implement its functional.

So, i have following code:

```cs
public class SimpleConfigurator : Configurator
{
    public int FieldA { get; set; }
    public override bool IsDataClassReadyToUse()
    {
        return ParentDataClass.FieldA == FieldA;
    }
}

public class ComplexConfigurator : Configurator
{
    public virtual List<int> FieldsB { get; set; }
    public override bool IsDataClassReadyToUse()
    {
        return ParentDataClass.FieldsB.All(x => FieldsB.Any(y => y == x));
    }
}

public abstract class Configurator
{
    public int ConfiguratorId { get; set; }
    public virtual DataClass ParentDataClass { get; set; }
    public abstract bool IsDataClassReadyToUse();
}

public class DataClass
{
    public int DataClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual Configurator Configurator { get; set; }
    public int FieldA { get; set; }
    public virtual List<int> FieldsB { get; set; }
}

public class DataDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DataClass> DataClasses { get; set; }
}
```

But the problem appears when i try use `DataClass` instance with `Configurator` of type `ComplexConfigurator`.

Because of LazyLoading i need to load `FieldsB` from `ComplexConfigurator`, but `abstract class Configurator` doesn't contain such field and i can't write such code:

```cs
new DataDbContext().DataClasses
                   .Include(m => m.Configurator)
                   .Include(m => m.Configurator.FieldsB);
```

I tried to disable LazyLoading, adding such constructor in `DataDbContext`:

```cs
public DataDbContext()
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

But when i try get access to `FieldsB` it still be null.

So, how can i implement such architecture with Entity Framework?

Or maybe i should choose another architecture for such task?

Comment: Your `DataDbContext` does not have a `DbSet` of `Configurator`, so I'd be surprised if you were able to access the `Configurator` member, let alone the `FieldsB` property.

Comment: @Gary This example works fine with `SimpleConfigurator` and we can easily access to its instances even withoud `DbSet` in `DataDbContext`. I thought, that Entity Framework may itself create database for `Configurator` objects. It is not true?

Comment: Have you tried `.Include("Configurator.FieldsB")`. I don't currently have time to set up a local DB and test it, but theoretically that should attempt to load the properties in question; I can't say that the generated SQL will be efficient at all though.

Comment: @Richard I get `A specified Include path is not valid` error.

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin change the `List<int>` in your classes to `ICollection<int>`.

Comment: @Richard Already done. But is it really important?

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin it is necessary for lazy loading, I was just more curious if it was doing something else under the covers that would allow it to work for your situation. I'm assuming that it did not? Any chance you can post a SQL script for the tables and some data?

Comment: Why did you disable lazy loading? That means: *no loading*, not *eager loading*. Lazy loading is your only chance here. But there's another issue: you can't map a `List<int>` to a database field/entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try access you configurator such as

`((ComplexConfigurator)yourObject.Configurator).FieldsB`

But I'm afraid EF works wrong with `List<int>` property (when I tried do that sometimes I've got a fail) and better way is to create class `Option` and field `List<Option> Options` into your configurator instead of List with integers.

You also should check your DB scheme (there's should be a table "Configurators" with idenitifator field and all SimpleConfigurator and ComplexConfigurator's fields). May be you should add `DbSet<Configurator>` into your DbContext definition.

You can read this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for getting more information about inheritance and EF.